# Prolog: Build a list with repeated elements of other list

Tags: list, prolog

I need construct a predicate who receive a list, check who are the repeated elements and return other list with them. Example:

```
?- rep_elements([a,b,c,a,b,d], Xs).
Xs = [a,b].
```

I start building a basic structure, but I don't now how to finish this predicate, or if this it the better way:

```
exists(Elem, [Elem|_]).
exists(Elem, [H|T]) :-
    exists(Elem, T).

rep_elements([], []).
rep_elements([H|T], [Y|Z]) :-
    exists(H, T),
    rep_elements(T, Z).
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prolog: splitting a list into two lists (unique items / duplicate items)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850183/prolog-splitting-a-list-into-two-lists-unique-items-duplicate-items)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I suggest we use a more descriptive predicate name, `list_uniqdups`.

We define `list_uniqdups/2` based upon [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`tpartition/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915), [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915) and [`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915):

```
list_uniqdups([],[]).
list_uniqdups([X|Xs0],Ys0) :-
   tpartition(=(X),Xs0,Es,Xs),
   if_(Es=[], Ys0=Ys, Ys0=[X|Ys]),
   list_uniqdups(Xs,Ys).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- list_uniqdups([a,b,c,a,b,d],Xs).  % query as given by the OP
Xs = [a,b].                          % expected result

?- list_uniqdups([a,c,b,a,b,d],Xs).  % similar query
Xs = [a,b].                          % same result

?- list_uniqdups([b,c,a,a,b,d],Xs).  % now, `b` comes before `a`
Xs = [b,a].                          % retain the original order

?- list_uniqdups([a,a,a,a,b],Xs).
Xs = [a].                            % remove all duplicates
```

Note that all above queries succeed deterministically.

Comment: @false. Highlighting ok? (should be somewhat more decent than before)

Comment: That is a very interesting solution. I'll study more closely meta-predicates to understand what make possible this solution. Thanks!

Comment: @RodrigoE. By all means! Meta-predicates enable an idiomatic high-level programming style. For a start with meta-predicates, I suggest you **first** look at `maplist/2` ( more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915 and https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#maplist ). Learn how to use it and how it works. Then return and study `tpartition/4`.

Answer (score 3):

Let's re-work your code step-by-step!

1. The predicate `exists/2` is covered by the widely available [`member/2`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#member). Let's use *that* one!

   ```
   rep_elements([], []).
   rep_elements([H|T], [Y|Z]) :-
      member(H, T),
      rep_elements(T, Z).
   ```
2. [As @CapelliC said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33185935/4609915), `rep_elements/2` is missing a clause; we add one using [`non_member/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10322639)!

   ```
   rep_elements([H|T], Z) :-
      non_member(T,H),
      rep_elements(T,Z).
   ```
3. Let re-run the query the OP gave!

   ```
   ?- rep_elements([a,b,c,a,b,d],Xs).
     Xs = [a,b]
   ; false.
   ```
4. OK! Are we done? Not quite! Consider the following query and the answers we get:

   ```
   ?- rep_elements([a,a,a,a,b],Xs).
     Xs = [a,a,a]                 % (1) duplicate items are retained
   ; Xs = [a,a,a]                 % (2) redundant answer
   ; Xs = [a,a,a]                 % (2)
   ; Xs = [a,a,a]                 % (2)
   ; Xs = [a,a,a]                 % (2)
   ; Xs = [a,a,a]                 % (2)
   ; false.                       % (3) leaves behind useless choicepoint
   ```
5. What's next? Take a step back and work on the specification!

Comment: Only to explain, I usualy use my own predicates (`exists/2` instead `member/2` and so on) because so I can check step by step the predicate running when I'm debugging, what isn't possible with buil-in predicates.

Answer (score 2):

rep_elements/2 is missing the handling of non duplicated elements.

If exists/2 would also 'return' the list T after having removed the duplicates found, then we could use the cleaned list for the recursion, and the task would be complete. Of course, exists/2 should become exists/3, and maybe renamed to a better, more descriptive name.

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively check if the head of the list is in the tail of the list then add it to Result.
Your solution can be modified as:

```
exists(Elem, [Elem|_]).
exists(Elem, [H|T]) :-
     exists(Elem, T).
/* IF you get empty list*/
rep_elements([], []).

/* If repetition found in list then joining it to head of list*/
rep_elements([H|T], Result) :-
     exists(H, T),
     rep_elements(T, [H|Result]).

/* If head of list is not found in the Tail of list*/
rep_elements(H|T, Result):-
     not(exists(H,T)),
     rep_elements(T,Result).
```

This should work.