# Prolog - remove from a list all repetitive elements (only keep unique elements)

Tags: prolog

so i have a problem in Prolog saying that i have to remove from a list all repetitive  elements. ex: `L=[1,2,1,4,1,3,4]` => `R=[2,3]`. I am not allowed to use any built in predicates. I know how to make it to remove duplicates ( like `L=[1,2,1,4,1,3,4]` => `R=[1,2,3]`), but i need only the elements that appear only once in the list.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: @lurker. Same question as: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33259691/4609915

Comment: @repeat yes, I originally cited that one as a duplicate, *except* in this case the OP has specified *not allowed to use any built-in predicates*, whereas that linked question seems to allow them (and all the answers

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have defined a service predicate `count_occurrences(Elem, List, Count).`

Then we can visit the list, passing the original as well, and decide element by element if we need to keep or discard it.